# How can you run code stored on a string variable on C#?

Tags: c#, string, variables, macros

I'm kind of new with C#. I was just wondering if there's a way to run code stored on a string var, for example:

```
string var = (int num = num1 * num2).ToString();
```

I read in another question it's called something like macro sustitutions ("macro sustitución" in spanish), so I want to know if any of you knows a way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: You should explain better, provide more code please

Comment: This should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6052640/365188

Comment: up voting b/c of the down votes

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you would want to use the CSharpCodeProvider unless you are building an interactive CSharp compiling app. Anyways, check out these tutorials.

[Compiling and Running code at runtime](http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/04/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime/)

[CodeProject: Compiling and Executing Code at Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9019/Compiling-and-Executing-Code-at-Runtime)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method which returns a string called MultipleNumbers. It would look something like this:

```
 public string MultipleNumbers(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
    {
        string answer;
        return answer = (firstNumber * secondNumber).ToString();
    }
```

Your string would be:

```
string answer = MultipleNumbers(2, 4);
```

I would suggest not using var as a variable name since it is a reserved name. You can use var in place of string like this:

```
var answer = MultipleNumbers(2, 4);
```

I hope this helps!